# NextJS Change Classname Fromat Generated by Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Here's the `JSX` for my `Heading` component:

```html
 <h1 className={classes.defaultHeading}>This is a heading</h1>
```

When I inspect the element in the browser, it looks like this:

```html
<h1 class="heading_defaultHeading__Rr0GL">This is a heading</h1>
```

I want classname format to be just the classname -- for example, I want the above generared code to look like this instead:

```html
<h1 class="defaultHeading">This is a heading</h1>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Use a `css` file (and import it in your `_app.tsx`) instead of a `module.css`

Comment: If you are looking to use the class for finding elements in the page (i.e. for UI testing or other) you can also add a `<h1 data-xxx="" ....>` attribute.

Comment: I just want to copy the html code and use it somewhere else. Using plain css file makes sense I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) which are going to *automatically creating a unique class name* (usefull for [component level css](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-component-level-css)).

Consider importing as many plain css [stylesheets](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet) as you want into your `pages/_app.js` file:

**`global.css`**

```css
.defaultHeading {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**`_app.js`**

```js
import '../global.css'
import '../other-css-file.css'

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

**`components/Heading.jsx`**

```html
<h1 className="defaultHeading">This is a heading</h1>
```